# failed connect (nginx with docker)

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm getting this failed to connect issues when it comes to communicating with other docker containers e.g Java server end.

This is the issue I'm getting

> nginx_1   | 2019/12/14 17:39:47 [error] 6#6: *2 connect() failed (111:
>   Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1,
>   server: , request: "GET /api/cards HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "http://172.19.0.4:80/api/cards", host: "localhost", referrer:
>   "http://localhost/"

Here is my Docker-Compose configuration (`docker-compose.development.yml`)

```
    version: '3'
    services:
      auth:
        build:
          context: ./auth
          dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
        volumes:
        - ./auth:/var/app
        - ~/.gradle/:/root/.gradle/
      client:
        build:
          context: ./client
          dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
        volumes:
        - ./client:/var/app/
        - /var/app/node_modules
      server:
        build:
          context: ./server
          dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
        volumes:
        - ./server:/var/app/
        - ~/.gradle/:/root/.gradle/
      nginx:
        image: nginx
        volumes:
        - ./server.dev.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        ports:
        - "80:80"
        depends_on:
        - auth
        - client
        - server
```

Here is my nginx docker configuration (server.dev.conf)

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        location /login/ {
            proxy_pass http://auth:80/login/;
        }
        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://server:80/api/;
        }
        location /resource/ {
            proxy_pass http://server:80/resource/;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://client:80;
            rewrite ^/home/.*$ / last;
        }
    }
```

Remind you this is for our development hosted locally. The production version uses SSL

Comment: Is the `server` container actually starting up, and is the process inside that actually listening on port 80?  It looks like you're overwriting the code in the image with content from your host via a `volumes:`, are you deleting or hiding the actual application?

Comment: How can I be sure, it's listening to port 80? And Yes it is building correctly. And if it isn't listening to that port correctly how can I force it to.  server_1  | INFO: Watched paths:  [/var/app/./src]
server_1  | Starting vert.x application...Dec 16, 2019 1:57:03 AM io.vertx.core.
impl.launcher.commands.Watcher
server_1  | INFO: Starting the vert.x application in redeploy mode
server_1  | Dec 16, 2019 1:57:04 AM io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.VertxIs
olatedDeployer
server_1  | INFO: Succeeded in deploying verticle